# How is Movement affected when Aborting?

Tags: movement, street-fighter-rpg

**When you choose to Abort to a different maneuver, how does your Movement value change?**

Some maneuvers can be used to Abort, allowing you to replace whatever other maneuver you played for the turn with the Abort maneuver.  This new maneuver has different stats for Speed, Damage, and Move.  What happens if you are midway through movement for the turn?

Possibilities:

- You change to the new Move value and change the amount of remaining movement points you have by the difference between the old and the new.

  - If this reduces your movement points to below 0, they simply become 0.
  - If this reduces your movement points to below 0, then Aborting is illegal.
- You keep the old Move value, and thus make no change.
- Aborting ends the movement phase and proceeds to the action phase, thus making it irrelevant.

**Which of these interpretations, if any, are accurate?**

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I can provide is that you can't interrupt your own action, so it should never affect your character mid-movement.

> The new Abort Maneuver becomes your action for that combat turn, **allowing you to interrupt another character's action** if your new maneuver has a higher Speed.

Comment: Fascinating... I never considered this interpretation.  I was under the impression that you could abort essentially at "any time", but perhaps you can't do during your own turn.  That has serious tactical consequences.

Comment: It does otherwise say it can be done at any point in the combat turn, and if you interrupt a movement of another character, they still get their remaining movement after you make the switch

Answer (score 1):

The rules don't require that the Move stat of your Abort Maneuver should be equal or higher than the previous maneuver. Simply uses the new maneuver stats, but consider that you may have already made some movement in the combat turn. If your new Move rating does not allow you to move forward any longer, your character just stops and then you perform your action, considering the new Speed (to check if you can perform before any other maneuver in the turn).

Some player may exploit this to perform a maneuver with a higher Move stat and then perform the Abort Maneuver with a lower Move stat, gaining some floor on the arena, but the trade-off is the expenditure of a Willpower point. It can't be done forever. Also, Abort Maneuvers are usually defensive, so there isn't much point in using this strategy than to save your character from taking a hit.